# How to open new page by button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am new to react. I am learning how to open a new page in new path in react.

this is my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import { Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "assets/css/material-dashboard-react.css?v=1.5.0";
import indexRoutes from "routes/index.jsx";
import CreateUser from "views/User/CreateUser.jsx";

const hist = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hist}>
    <Switch>
      {indexRoutes.map((prop, key) => {
        return <Route path={prop.path} component={prop.component} key={key} 
/>;
      })}
    </Switch>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The indexRoutes will render my dashboard

```
import Dashboard from "@material-ui/icons/Dashboard";
import Person from "@material-ui/icons/Person";
import LibraryBooks from "@material-ui/icons/LibraryBooks";
import BubbleChart from "@material-ui/icons/BubbleChart";
import LocationOn from "@material-ui/icons/LocationOn";
import Notifications from "@material-ui/icons/Notifications";
import Unarchive from "@material-ui/icons/Unarchive";
import DashboardPage from "views/Dashboard/Dashboard.jsx";
import UserProfile from "views/UserProfile/UserProfile.jsx";
import TableList from "views/TableList/TableList.jsx";
import Typography from "views/Typography/Typography.jsx";
import Icons from "views/Icons/Icons.jsx";
import Maps from "views/Maps/Maps.jsx";
import NotificationsPage from "views/Notifications/Notifications.jsx";
import UpgradeToPro from "views/UpgradeToPro/UpgradeToPro.jsx";

import User from "views/User/User.jsx";

const dashboardRoutes = [
  {
    path: "/dashboard",
    sidebarName: "Dashboard",
    navbarName: "Material Dashboard",
    icon: Dashboard,
    component: DashboardPage
  },
  {
    path: "/profile",
    sidebarName: "User Profile",
    navbarName: "Profile",
    icon: Person,
    component: UserProfile
  },
  {
    path: "/table",
    sidebarName: "Table List",
    navbarName: "Table List",
    icon: "content_paste",
    component: TableList
  },
  {
    path: "/typography",
    sidebarName: "Typography",
    navbarName: "Typography",
    icon: LibraryBooks,
    component: Typography
  },
  {
    path: "/icons",
    sidebarName: "Icons",
    navbarName: "Icons",
    icon: BubbleChart,
    component: Icons
  },
  {
    path: "/maps",
    sidebarName: "Maps",
    navbarName: "Map",
    icon: LocationOn,
    component: Maps
  },
  {
    path: "/notifications",
    sidebarName: "Notifications",
    navbarName: "Notifications",
    icon: Notifications,
    component: NotificationsPage
  },
  {
    path: "/user",
    sidebarName: "User",
    navbarName: "User",
    icon: Person,
    component: User
  },
  {
    path: "/upgrade-to-pro",
    sidebarName: "Upgrade To PRO",
    navbarName: "Upgrade To PRO",
    icon: Unarchive,
    component: UpgradeToPro
  },
  { redirect: true, path: "/", to: "/dashboard", navbarName: "Redirect" }
];

export default dashboardRoutes;
```

However, I want to open a new page by clicking a button. For example, this is my user page in my dashboard. I successfully to access this user page by clicking the user in my sidebar with path localhost/user. I have created a button in user page. I want to navigate the path from localhost/user to localhost/createuser and display createuser page when I clicked the button.

```
import React from "react";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";
import GridItem from "components/Grid/GridItem.jsx";
import GridContainer from "components/Grid/GridContainer.jsx";
import Table from "components/Table/Table.jsx";
import Card from "components/Card/Card.jsx";
import CardHeader from "components/Card/CardHeader.jsx";
import CardBody from "components/Card/CardBody.jsx";

import Button from "components/CustomButtons/Button.jsx";
import CardFooter from "components/Card/CardFooter.jsx";

const styles = {
  cardCategoryWhite: {
    "&,& a,& a:hover,& a:focus": {
      color: "rgba(255,255,255,.62)",
      margin: "0",
      fontSize: "14px",
      marginTop: "0",
      marginBottom: "0"
    },
    "& a,& a:hover,& a:focus": {
      color: "#FFFFFF"
    }
  },
  cardTitleWhite: {
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    marginTop: "0px",
    minHeight: "auto",
    fontWeight: "300",
    fontFamily: "'Roboto', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif",
    marginBottom: "3px",
    textDecoration: "none",
    "& small": {
      color: "#777",
      fontSize: "65%",
      fontWeight: "400",
      lineHeight: "1"
    }
  }
};

function createUser() {
  console.log("lolo");
}

function TableList(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <GridContainer>
      <GridItem xs={12} sm={12} md={12}>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={createUser()}>Create User</Button>
        <Card>
          <CardHeader color="primary">
            <h4 className={classes.cardTitleWhite}>User List</h4>
            <p className={classes.cardCategoryWhite}>
              {/*Here is a subtitle for this table*/}
            </p>
          </CardHeader>
          <CardBody>
            <Table
              tableHeaderColor="primary"
              tableHead={["Name", "Country", "City", "Salary"]}
              tableData={[
                ["Dakota Rice", "Niger", "Oud-Turnhout", "$36,738"],
                ["Minerva Hooper", "Curaçao", "Sinaai-Waas", "$23,789"],
                ["Sage Rodriguez", "Netherlands", "Baileux", "$56,142"],
                ["Philip Chaney", "Korea, South", "Overland Park", "$38,735"],
                ["Doris Greene", "Malawi", "Feldkirchen in Kärnten", "$63,542"],
                ["Mason Porter", "Chile", "Gloucester", "$78,615"],
                ["LALA", "NOOB", "LOL", "$12345"]
              ]}
            />
          </CardBody>
          <CardFooter>
            <Button color="primary">Update Profile</Button>
          </CardFooter>
        </Card>
      </GridItem>
    </GridContainer>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(TableList);
```

I have tried several methods shown in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) but none of them works. Does anyone have any idea on this ?

Comment: React knows nothing about "page"s. You'd use whatever JS provides you to solve this task

Comment: @zerkms, my page means component, I have create a new component -createuser. I am just not sure how to use onclicked button to display this component.

Comment: @Asthmatic, is not change of url, is change of path. For example, I able to change the path from localhost/user to localhost/maps because I have set the component and path in indexRoutes. But I fail to create a new path- localhost/createuser to render new component. If I set createuser in indexRoutes, it will display in the sidebar as well which I dont want to.